# flutter attach - Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Running flutter attach from android studio terminal not working. Showing error Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.

Terminal output:

```
flutter attach
Checking for advertised Dart observatories...

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 50ca8df4de508ad3)

Crash report written to /Users/johnnykuttymathew/Documents/Work/Code/<project>/flutter_04.log;
```

How to avoid this? This is happening for all the projects. Even foefreshly created projects.

Flutter doctor output.

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale en-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at /usr/local/custom/flutter
    • Framework revision 7a4c33425d (3 weeks ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
    • Engine revision 52c7a1e849
    • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/johnnykuttymathew/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2, Build version 10E125
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    • Dart plugin version 191.7019
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone Xʀ • 98882BC0-AF96-4B19-B530-78A7EFAA5DFF • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: What's the crash report?

Answer (score 1):

To install the Flutter and Dart plugins:

-> Start Android Studio.

-> Open plugin preferences (Preferences > Plugins on macOS, File > Settings > Plugins on Windows & Linux).

-> Select Browse repositories, select the Flutter plugin and click Install.

-> Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.

-> Click Restart when prompted.

Comment: Did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

a) Please double check if all the dependent components are installed properly.
b) You also need to check if multiple android-sdk’s are not installed, if yes uninstall as two sdk’s may create issue.
c) Reset Android-sdk path if its set as Android_Home (many dev did this and got it fixed)
d) Sometime flutters dependencies faces permission issue which could be fixed by run sudo su on terminal if you are on Mac or command prompt on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading Flutter / Dart pluginsm and change the channel to stable using `flutter channel stable`.